# Android APK error after updating from the Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-internet

I have a running application on Google Play and it does not work without an internet connection. If you do not have an internet connection you can not pass by the splash screen.

Yesterday I've tried to give an update from Google Play, I install the APK to the store and wait for the update. APK that I download from my computer was working perfect, I've removed the test APK from my device and upload it from the Google Play. After I download the new one it started to give internet connection error and I could not do anything from the application.

The necessary permissions are taken and I have a proper network connection on my mobile device. I use data from other apps such as Facebook or a browser from both Wi-Fi and mobile network.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Lastly, when I arrange the upload, I didn't change anything at all besides the what's new text on Google Play.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Every time you make a new release to Google play you have to change versioncode and version name in the manifest file, have u changed it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I clean the project before export a build, than I uploaded a new APK to the store. That's all. A bit silly but solved my problem.